# Problem with DeclareMathSizes

Tags: align, amsmath

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[square,colon,authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyheadings}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{comment}
\DeclareMathSizes{11}{20}{7}{5}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 &   &  \text{where cohesive modulus,}~k_c &= 1400\left(\frac{N}{m^2}\right)\\
 &   &  \text{frictional modulus, }~k_\varphi &= 8200\left(\frac{N}{m^2}\right) \\
 &   &  \text{exponent of sinkage, }~n&=0.8\\
 &   &  \text{wheel width, }~b_w&=0.08(m)\\
 z_{rw}&=\frac{\left(\frac{3W_W\cos\theta}{(3-n)(k_c+b_wk_\varphi)\sqrt{d_w}}\right)^\frac{2}{(2n+1)}}{N} &  \text{wheel diameter, }~n&=0.14(m)\\
 &   &  \text{number of wheels, }~N&=6\\
 &   &  \text{cohesion, }~c &= 170\left(\frac{N}{m^2}\right) \\
 &   &  \text{slope angle, }~\theta &= 30\deg(deg) \\
 &   &   W_W&=48.6(N) \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am getting this output, actually, I was trying to put the equation to the left middle and the definitions to the right. But the equation seems too small, and I couldn't make it bigger, I've tried \DeclareMathSizes but it doesn't do anything. Is there any way I can make it bigger, and maybe is there a better way to write definitions?

Comment: You should use `\@xipt` or `10.95`. But the result will not be pretty.

Comment: Which value should I change with that?

Comment: the first argument is the current text size, you have 11 which does not match your font size 10.95 as set by the `11pt` option

Comment: For historical reasons, 11pt is actually 10.95pt; but the output will be really ugly. If you want to try, `\makeatletter\DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{20}{7}{5}\makeatother`. You also need `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}` before `\documentclass`. Try and see.

Comment: 20 7 5 was just random numbers. I tried {10.95}{15}{14}{10} it looks good I think, but you know there is a space next to the equation due to aligning, is there a way to close that space, by the way thanks for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, for historical reasons, the `11pt` option chooses the 10.95 as font size.

However, `\DeclareMathSizes` is not the answer.

The reason why the formula appears “too small” is the outer fraction: just use `\frac{1}{N}` in front of the rest.

I'd avoid unsightly alignments that don't help the reader, but rather confuse the output. The equals signs in the specification for the coefficients are not related to one another, but the descriptions are.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\[
z_{rw}=\frac{1}{N}
       \left(\frac{3W_W\cos\theta}{(3-n)(k_c+b_wk_\varphi)\sqrt{d_w}}\right)^\frac{2}{(2n+1)}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
where\\
cohesive modulus    & $k_c = \qty{1400}{\newton\per\square\meter}$ \\
frictional modulus  & $k_\varphi = \qty{8200}{\newton\per\square\meter}$ \\
exponent of sinkage & $n=0.8$ \\
wheel width         & $b_w=\qty{0.08}{\meter}$ \\
wheel diameter      & $n=\qty{0.14}{\meter}$ \\
number of wheels    & $N=6$ \\
cohesion            & $c= \qty{170}{\newton\per\square\meter}$ \\
slope angle         & $\theta = \qty{30}{\degree}$ \\
                    & $W_W = \qty{48.6}{\newton}$
\end{tabular}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `fancyheadings` has been deprecated for *many* years and all it does is to load `fancyhdr` and issue a very long warning.

Also `epstopdf` is not necessary, as it's automatically used in case of need.

I recommend `siunitx` for the quantities.

A different approach:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
z_{rw}=\frac{1}{N}
       \left(\frac{3W_W\cos\theta}{(3-n)(k_c+b_wk_\varphi)\sqrt{d_w}}\right)^\frac{2}{(2n+1)}
\\
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{\qquad}ll@{}}
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l@{}}{where $W_W = \qty{48.6}{\newton}$ and} \\
cohesive modulus    & $k_c = \qty{1400}{\newton\per\square\meter}$ &
frictional modulus  & $k_\varphi = \qty{8200}{\newton\per\square\meter}$ \\
exponent of sinkage & $n=0.8$ &
wheel width         & $b_w=\qty{0.08}{\meter}$ \\
wheel diameter      & $n=\qty{0.14}{\meter}$ &
number of wheels    & $N=6$ \\
cohesion            & $c= \qty{170}{\newton\per\square\meter}$ &
slope angle         & $\theta = \qty{30}{\degree}$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm new in LaTeX, therefore I couldn't manage to do it. And also about headings, I'm writing an abstract for a conference and their example paper had these headings, so I didn't try to change it.